# Is system.nanoTime() wrong?

Tags: java, time

I'm writing an FTP client app and  used System.nanoTime() at two points in my code and the difference in seconds is returned as 18, whereas my program only takes 2 seconds...Check the logs in onPostExecute method... 
Why is this happening and how do I solve it?

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    try
        {
        if(perflag)
            return "Not yet";
        String ipadd= ip.getText().toString();
            BufferedReader br;
            int port =Integer.parseInt(portt.getText().toString());
        while(true) {
            socket = new Socket(ipadd, port);
            //Button conn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.connectb);
            if(startflag)
            {
                starttime=System.nanoTime();
                startflag=false;
            }
            //conn.setEnabled(false);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedOutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bo, true);
            file = br.readLine();
            if (file.equals("Finished"))
            {
               // socket.close();
                Log.i("stat","above sock");
               // Thread.sleep(1000);
                //socket= new Socket(ipadd,port);
                //br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                datas=br.readLine();
                data=Double.parseDouble(datas);
                Log.i("stat",datas);
                br.close();
                socket.close();
                finflag=true;
                break;
            }
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
            File f = new File(path, "/" + file);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            int i=0;
            while(f.exists())
            {
                f= new File(path,"/"+"("+i+")"+file);
                i++;
            }
            pw.println("done");
            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            publishProgress(file);

            while ((len = is.read(buff)) != -1) {


                fos.write(buff, 0, len);

            }

            publishProgress(file);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
    {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter a proper IP and port!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                start();
            }
        });
        nfe.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch(java.net.UnknownHostException un)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter a proper IP and port!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                start();
            }
        });
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Enter a proper IP and port!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        un.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(java.net.NoRouteToHostException no)
    {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"There is no active server at the specified IP and port!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                start();
            }
        });
        no.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)

    {
            Log.i("error",e.getMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occurred!Try checking storage permissions or connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    start();
                }
            });
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    endtime=System.nanoTime();
    return "Not Yet";
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... para)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(para);
    trans.setText("Transfering file: "+para[0]);
}
protected void onPostExecute(String as) {
    start();

    if(finflag)
    {
        startflag=true;
        Log.i("start",String.valueOf(starttime));
        Log.i("end",String.valueOf(endtime));
        totaltime=endtime-starttime;

        Log.i("total",String.valueOf(totaltime));
        //totaltime/=100000000;
        double time=totaltime/1000000000;
        Log.i("time in secs",String.valueOf(time));
        double rate= (double)(data/time);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Transfer successful!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Average transfer rate: "+rate+"MBps",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finflag=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @sumanth: That's minimal?!?

Comment: Not very minimal, also not complete. Where do you declare `starttime` and `endtime`? Are those `double` as well? Better make them `long` if they are.

Comment: @Thilo they're long

Comment: Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: How about `totaltime`? Better keep variable definitions as local as possible (then we would not have to ask).

Comment: @Thilo i'll remember that. In this case,total time is long too

Answer (score 2):

There is little point in doing integer division to get seconds, as that will only return you whole seconds; you don't need to use `nanoTime` for whole seconds. Change:

```
double time=totaltime/1000000000;
```

To

```
double time=totaltime/1000000000d; // (or totaltime/1000000000.0)
```

But the divisor you are using is fine; nano is 10<sup>-9</sup>. However, I see a commented-out line in your code just above your division:

```
        //totaltime /= 100000000;
double time=totaltime/1000000000;
```

In that line, your divisor only had 8 zeros, not 9 zeros. Are you sure that the "18" seconds that you have posted are coming from `double time=totaltime/1000000000;` and not from `totaltime /= 100000000;` ? Because an actual time of 1.8 seconds would look like 18 seconds if you had one zero too few in your divisor.

As commenters have mentioned, the problem is really the magic constant which makes it easy to get the wrong number of zeroes.

Here are a few ways to address this:

- Java allows you to put underscores in a number for any reason; you can write `totaltime / 1_000_000_000d` to make it more visible how many zeroes you are using.
- Java also allows scientific notation for doubles, so you can also write `totaltime / 1e9`
- Java has built in functions for conversion of time units; however, since you want fractions of a second, you can't simply say `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(totaltime)` (which would round down to `1` second). You can however say `totaltime / (double) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1)`

Comment: To avoid such bugs, one can specify constants in scientific notation: `1E9` is much less error prone than `1000000000` ...

Comment: Please use `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(<value>)` (or whatever timeunit is needed) instead of defining your own constants all over the place. This problem is easily adressed with classes contained in the jdk

Comment: no .it was working fine.I just checked and i put the starttime at the wrong place -_-...i know...dumb..sorry..But thanks for ur time :)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration                          // Represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline.
.ofNanos(                         // Represent a count of nanoseconds.
    System.nanoTime() - start     // Calculate elapsed nanoseconds.
)                                 // Returns a `Duration` object.
.toString()                       // Generates text in standard ISO 8601 format for elapsed time.
```

> PT2.020615864S

## `Duration`

I would use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class. This class represents a span-of-time unattached to the timeline, in a resolution of hours-minutes-seconds-nanoseconds.

Subtract the two counts of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) returned by calls to [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()). Pass result to [`Duration.ofNanos`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#ofNanos(long)).

```
long start = System.nanoTime() ;
Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis( 2 ) ); 
long stop = System.nanoTime() ;

Duration d = Duration.ofNanos( stop - start ) ;

System.out.println( d ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dIMMCE).

> PT2.020615864S

Actually, in real code we need to handle the [Thread sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) getting interrupted (awoken).

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
try
{
    Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis( 2 ) ); 
} catch ( InterruptedException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
long stop = System.nanoTime();

Duration d = Duration.ofNanos( stop - start );

System.out.println( d );
```